# Listview inside NestedScrollview is not expanding after setting adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]I have tried setting android:fillViewport="true" but still when I setAdapter for the Listview which is inside the NestedScrollView it doesnot expand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn a ListView into a NestedScrollView, you must make your custom list. Here's how to do it:

```
class ExpandedListView(context: Context?) : ListView(context) {
        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context)

        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : this(context, attrs)

        constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

        override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
            val expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec)
            layoutParams.height = measuredHeight
        }
    }
```

Please utilize this on an XML file.

```
<com.yourpackage.ExpandedListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ... 
/>
```